# Hide header in stack navigator

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app, there is a drawer navigator nested inside a stack navigator. I want to hide the stack navigator header inside all drawer navigator screens, but visible on other screens

try headerShown: false, not work

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRqFt.png)[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Nk6.png)[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiPfj.png)

```js
const StackNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Shop"
      component={DrawerNavigator}
      options={{
        header: ({ navigation }) => (
          <Header
            statusBarProps={{ translucent: false }}
            placement="center"
            leftComponent={{
              icon: "menu",
              color: "#fff",
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()),
            }}
            centerComponent={{
              text: "Shopping",
              style: {
                fontSize: 24,
                color: "#fff",
              },
            }}
            containerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: "#F84930",
            }}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Login"
      component={Login}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Register"
      component={Register}
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProductDetail"
      component={ProductDetail}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: route.params.item.name,
        headerBackTitle: " return",
      })}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Comment: have you tried headerShown on the stack.navigator itself ?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: Please post pictures directly in SO. You can either directly import it, or use the built-in  link format `![hover note](http://web.site/ima.ge)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
}

Put this in your `<Stack.Screen` in your component

```
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
```